# ASG replacement with same IP

Tags: amazon-web-services

### Summary

When a node fails, or is otherwise removed, how can an ASG be configured to respawn that node with the same private IP as the one it is replacing?

I notice that there [is support](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/07/13/amazon-virtual-private-cloud-adds-ip-address-assignment/) for allocating an administrator chosen address but I'm not sure how to apply this to ASG's.

### Context

We have a service, [Consul](http://consul.io), that we're trying to make more robust ideally with ASG's since that can automatically respawn a terminated instance (failed or otherwise). The issue is that Consul consists of a set of masters and you can't just replace them with different nodes without explicitly joining the new node to the cluster and cleaning up the now defunct node.

So it seems simpler just to make a failed node get replaced with a fresh version of its former self. That primarily means it having the same private interface IP as before. How can this be accomplished?

More generally - how are people managing clustered services that have some kind of awareness of the participating nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of an [Elastic IP (EIP)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

1. Start by allocating an EIP that you want to always be connected to the instance in your ASG, this is done using the AWS CLI or through the AWS console (EC2 > Elastic IPs).
2. When that is done, you should add a script to your AMI that associate the new instance with your allocated EIP. Use the [aws ec2 associate-address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/allocate-address.html) command available in the AWS CLI tools. This script should be run on boot or whenever your application is ready.

By doing it this way, the new instance will be assigned the same public IP as the old instance had.

Comment: Thanks for the info but we need to IP's to be in a private network; this is not a public facing service. And it would be better if the IP could be an actual interface on the instance that the service can bind to.

Answer (score 1):

That's not now ASGs are supposed to be used.

Instead, put a load balancer (either ELB or one of your own creation) in front of your ASG nodes and then add/remove back-end nodes from the load balancer as needed.

If you need awareness of nodes participating in your ASG, then you can use the API to enumerate ASG instances.

Comment: We could use some external tool to watch the ASG and reconfigure the cluster as needed however it seemed simpler to just get the same IP assigned (if possible).

The issue with an LB is that the back end nodes speak to each other and track which are present (or not); they are not stateless. If we add/remove nodes enough then the cluster quorum will be lost since we need to explicitly rejoin new nodes and clean up the failed ones.